# Recovering 3D point from perspective projection.

Tags: geometry

Say I have a point $(X,Y,Z)$ and that point lines in a plane with gradient $(A,B,C,)^T.$ If I know the perspective projection of that point onto an image plane has the coordinates $(x,y)$ and the focal distance is $f$, how can I express the coordinates of the original 3D point using the gradient coefficients and the projected point?